# How to open Fontello Icons in new tab or window?

Tags: navigation

Coding/CSS/HTML is not my area of forte at all. I've figured out that this  (more or less) is how to make an external link open in a new window or tab. I'm working on a website that uses Fontello Icons for social media links and I'd like those links to open in a new tab/window so the individual would be able to keep a tab open with my website. Any and all help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be to add a target="_blank" parameter into your anchor tag. Something like:

```
<a href="example.com/url" target="_blank">&fontello_icon_here;</a>
```

The long answer depends on your context. I hope this helps! If it doesn't please update your question with specifics of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried what you had suggested and it didn't work. I've uploaded a photo to the original question. Hopefully that gives you a better idea? I apologize I can't be of more help but coding definitely is not my expertise.

Comment: @Kathy put your gloves on, you're gonna have to get your hands dirty and edit the template file of your theme that is responsible for the social links and add the `target="_blank"` part.